# Regex for names validation allow only letters and spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to validate using jQuery Validator if input only contains spaces, and allow space only if there's a letter inside it.

Note that it should also display error if name contains numbers. Allow only the space if it starts with a letter.

This is what I have so far that only allows letters and spaces:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letterswithspace", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "letters only");
```

Also tried this one but it trims the string and can't add a space between names:

```
first_name : {
    letterswithspace : true,
     required: {
         depends:function(){
             $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
             return true;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can trim value before passing to validator function then it will check for empty string.

Comment: @NitinDhomse, so how can we use it using my recent code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To match the terms:

- Expression can start only with a letter
- Expression can contain letters or spaces

You need to use this regex expression:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/
```

So in your js it should be:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letterswithspace", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, "letters only");
```

**Explanation**

1. `^[a-z]` means start with one letter
2. `[a-z\s]*$` means after accept zero or more letters or spaces

---

**Valid sentence**

If you want a valid sentence structure:

- Expression can start or end only with a letter
- Expression cannot contain consecutive spaces

use:

```
/^([a-z]+\s)*[a-z]+$/
```

---

**By the way**

2. These regex expressions do not accept capital letters. To add capital letters support instead of `a-z` use `a-zA-Z`

Comment: Thanks for the help with great explanation.

Comment: When I try this: `const x= /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$/` and test it like so `x.test(undefined)` it return `true`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use this regex expression:-

```
/^[a-zA-Z-,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/;
```

Example Without Jquery Validator using Javascript:- Its Work Fine [Javascript Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/5ugwgasd/)

Hope Its Work !!

Answer (score 1):

### **Jquery validation for Full Name using regular expression**

*Validation includes:*

1. Name not allow numbers.
2. Name allow alphabets only,not allow any special characters.

   ```
   <html>
   <body>
   <label>Full Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control name-valid">

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.name-valid').on('keypress', function(e) {
     var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]*$");
     var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
     if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    });
   });
   </script>  
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

For Demo Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shubhanshu/qkbchsag/30/)!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letterswithspace", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value); }, "letters only");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15066926)

Comment: Wow, thank you, been searching this for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

/^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/i.test(value) // insensitive case